# hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK() doesn't work

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am making a template in Drupal 8. At this moment, I made a theme in the /themes directory; there, I have my .theme file and a copy of the html.html.twig file from the core/themes/stable directory.

I have enabled Twig debugging mode and in the Chrome inspect tool I read the following.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--front.html.twig
   * html--.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
```

I added the following hook to the theme file.

```
function testTheme_suggestions_html_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $suggestions[] = 'html__testHTML';
}
```

After clearing the cache, there isn't any change to the file name suggestions.

Also I have activated `kint()` in html.html.twig file that is located in my theme root, but `kint()` also shows only these variables.

```
'theme_hook_suggestions' => array(2)
string(6) "html__"
string(11) "html__front"
```

Why doesn't the new suggestions appear?

Comment: Is this code even being hit?

Comment: well, this code resided in .theme file, i think yes it must be executed when site is loaded... (I in preprocess hook to be sure that that preprocess hook is executed i put in it  [ echo '<script>'; echo 'alert(" ")'; echo '</script>';], this way i can be sure that i am entering in preprocess hook. i have tried to do so in suggestions_html_alter but there nothing happens )

Comment: You need to know if it is being hit by using a debugger or exit. If you clear cache and it still isn't being hit, then you can start there.

Comment: That was a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function yourthemename_theme_suggestions_html_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'html__testHTML';
}
```

Replace "yourthemename" with your theme name.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! this works!!! now i see my mistake i thought that hook_theme mus be reappraised with my theme name, but only hook must be reappraise i this case!!!! (I was looking for solution more than 4 hours!!!!)